# jQuery on a SELECT not working in IE but works in all other browsers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a drop down menu to set/change a class on a div depending on the value of the option selected. This works fine in all my main browsers except IE7 and 8. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#outerwrapper').find('select').change(function () {
      var str1 = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      str1 = $(this).attr('value');
    });
    $("#swatch").removeClass().addClass('mycssclass_' + str1);
  })
  .change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerwrapper">
  <form action="/" method="POST" name="test">
    Choose: 
    <select id="in_clr" name="clr"><!-- By choosing an option from this list... -->
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <div id="swatch"><!-- I want jQuery to add a CSS class of mycssclass_1 (or 2 or 3) to this DIV -->
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried replacing **.change** with **.live("change",** but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but I know JQuery has a LOT of issues with CSS in IE.

Comment: this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z9Gp/) (1:1 copy & paste) runs well in my IE8

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector from: `$('#outerwrapper').find('select')` to: `$('#in_clr')`

From my experience, DOM Traversal over form elements can be odd in IE. You don't need the extra chaining anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can condense your coding down quite a bit to just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#outerwrapper select').change(function() {
        $("#swatch").removeClass().addClass('mycssclass_' + $(this).val());
     });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk2SZ/).

The `.ready` only runs once the element is available (you can change to using `.live` if you are using ajax-y stuff.

Note that this will bind the change event to all select elements -- use `#in_clr` if you only want to target that particular select.

As for why IE was failing, it was probably your `:selected` call or the `.attr()` as IE is very picky about attributes and properties.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help! Very much appreciated!